Position containers "horizontally off-center" on desktop; smoothly scale down "centrally" for mobile
I am trying to make a simple responsive page.

On mobile things scale down fine, are centered, and fit the window width.

On desktop, the container and contents scale up to max width but are all always horizontally centered on screen.


Where the browser width allows it, I want the container divs be positioned at different distances from the viewport side. e.g. one %5 from the right, or another 8% from the left? For a design aesthetic.
I've tried things like using calc on vh width, and media queries but I cant get it to work without images being cut off when the browser is scaled down, or big "jumps" in sizes happen. The images always get cut off on the sides any ideas?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Basura</title>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
      margin: 20px; 
      padding: 0;      
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 1.2;
    }

    /* Link styles */
    a {
      color: blue; /* Set link color to blue */
      text-decoration: none; /* Remove default underline */
    }

    /* Hover and active link styles */
    a:hover,
    a:active,
    a:focus {
      text-decoration: underline; /* Underline link on hover, click, or focus */
    }

    .container {
      background-color:;
      margin-bottom: 80px;
      padding: 0px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column; /* Change flex direction to column */
      position: relative; /* Add position relative */
      margin-top: 0px; /* Add margin-top for spacing */
    }


    /* Custom CSS for text boxes */
    .textbox {
      background-color: white;
      max-width: 600px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-top: 20px; /* Add margin-top for spacing */
      margin-left: auto; /* Align to the right */
      margin-bottom: 0px; /* Add margin-bottom for spacing */
      text-align: left; /* Align text to the left */
    }


  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container first-container" style="max-width: 1000px">
    <div style="background-color: lightgreen; width: 100%">
<center><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?car" style="max-width: 100%"></center></div>

    <div class="textbox">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="container second-container" style="max-width: 800px">
    <div style="background-color: orange; width: 100%">
<center><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?cat" style="max-width: 100%"></center>
    </div>

    <div class="textbox">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div> 
  </div>



</body>
</html>




You can achieve this by using CSS media queries and the margin-left and margin-right properties. I have given some CSS Below that should help resolve this issue. Let me know if you have any questions.
HTML/CSS:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Basura</title>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
      margin: 20px; 
      padding: 0;      
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 1.2;
    }

    /* Link styles */
    a {
      color: blue; /* Set link color to blue */
      text-decoration: none; /* Remove default underline */
    }

    /* Hover and active link styles */
    a:hover,
    a:active,
    a:focus {
      text-decoration: underline; /* Underline link on hover, click, or focus */
    }

    .container {
      background-color:;
      margin-bottom: 80px;
      padding: 0px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column; /* Change flex direction to column */
      position: relative; /* Add position relative */
      margin-top: 0px; /* Add margin-top for spacing */
    }

    /* Custom CSS for text boxes */
    .textbox {
      background-color: white;
      max-width: 600px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-top: 20px; /* Add margin-top for spacing */
      margin-left: auto; /* Align to the right */
      margin-bottom: 0px; /* Add margin-bottom for spacing */
      text-align: left; /* Align text to the left */
    }

    /* New CSS */
    @media (min-width: 768px) { /* Adjust this value based on when you want to apply these styles */
      .first-container {
        margin-right: 5%; /* 5% from the right */
      }

      .second-container {
        margin-left: 8%; /* 8% from the left */
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container first-container" style="max-width: 1000px">
    <div style="background-color: lightgreen; width: 100%">
<center><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?car" style="max-width: 100%"></center></div>

    <div class="textbox">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="container second-container" style="max-width: 800px">
    <div style="background-color: orange; width: 100%">
<center><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?cat" style="max-width: 100%"></center>
    </div>

    <div class="textbox">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div> 
  </div>

</body>
</html>

By the way, not sure if this is intentional but background-color:; has no value to it. this is not much of a big deal, but figured I would point that out.

thank you so much!
i have tried a method like this before, but what my challenge is, is that when you have this code and make the browser width smaller, images start to get cut off on the sides (because of the margin)... until the media query kicks in.
i wondered - is there a way so that until the media query kicks in - if the edge of the container/contents hits the side, it can know to scale down so it doesnt look bad?

Yes @hellofromlondon there is a way you can handle this. You can use the calc() function in CSS to dynamically calculate the width of your containers based on the viewport width.
Try implementing this CSS:
`@media (min-width: 768px) { /* Adjust this value based on when you want to apply these styles /
.first-container {
margin-right: 5%; / 5% from the right /
width: calc(95% - 10px); / Calculate width dynamically */
}
.second-container {
margin-left: 8%; /* 8% from the left /
width: calc(92% - 10px); / Calculate width dynamically */
}
}`

Has this helped you @hellofromlondon ? If it has, you can mark this question as accepted if you would like :)

Thank you lil_physyziX that does exactly what I wanted. To help me understand canI ask - why are we using the 95%-10px, and 92%-10x. And why is it 10px?

95% - 10px and 92% - 10px are being used to calculate widths as a percentage of the parent container’s width, but then subtracting a fixed amount of pixels. This can be help for creating layouts that have a consistent ‘gutter’ or margin.
The 10px value you’re asking about is being used as a fixed space or margin. The reason for using 10px specifically depends on the overall design. I chose 10px because it provides the right amount of space for the design to look good at various screen sizes. At least in my opinion anyways. @hellofromlondon

I hope this has helped you :)

it has and thankyou for explaining. this has got me off to a good start., thanks for generously helping. have a great friday.

Thank you! you as well :) Im actually working on another one of your questions right now. how to get specifically positioned divs to correctly resize based on browser width

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
